# Java: Why aren't my variables passed to the constructor usable by my method?

Tags: java, class, methods

So I declared some variables in main and created a new object; passing the variables as arguments to the constructor. Now, when I call a method inside the class, I would have thought that these variables would be accessible by the method, WITHOUT having to pass them as arguments to it. Is this not so?

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Step2_lab11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int TAO = 50;
        final double DELTA_MINUTES = 0.1;

        System.out.println("VINETS AVKYLNINGSTID \n");
        System.out.println("Ange vinets temperatur:");

        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        double wineTemp = userIn.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Vinets önskade temperatur:");
        double preferredTemp = userIn.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Kylens/frysens temperatur:");
        double chillTemp = userIn.nextDouble();

        WineChiller wineChiller = new WineChiller(wineTemp, preferredTemp, chillTemp);

    }

}
```

Here's the class WineChiller.java:

```
public class WineChiller {

    public WineChiller(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {
        getChillingTime();

    }

    public void getChillingTime() {

        while(wineTemp>preferredTemp)
        {
            elapsedTime += DELTA_MINUTES;
            double dT = (wineTemp - chillTemp) * DELTA_MINUTES  / TAO;
            wineTemp -= dT;
        }
        System.out.println(Math.round(elapsedTime));

    }

}
```

Why can't getChillingTime resolve wineTemp etc to variables?

EDITED TO ADD: Much appreciate the pointers guys. But there's an additional caveat! The instructions seems to imply that the class WineChiller should ONLY contain the constructor and the method getChillingTime, and that getChillingTime SHOULD NOT take arguments! Is there a typo in the assignment paper?

Comment: Simple ... There is no input parameter for the method getChillingTime.

Comment: Things passed to the constructor are just that, things the constructor could use, it won't nessissariliy store them, it might perform some maths with them, or normalise them then store them. Its entirely up to the constructor what to do with them and your constructor has decided to do nothingwith them. Note that you can autogenerate contructors in most good IDEs based on the objects fields (eg in netbeans Atl+insert brings up the option)

Comment: Behaving in the way you imagine would cause real problems down the line; having multiple constructors can be very useful but it would be a real hodge podge (both for you and the compiler) to figure out exactly what the objects fields were based on multiple constructors taking different variables all negotiating to have their variables as fields. And then garanteeing that the class definately has everything it needs to run any of its methods irrespective of which constructor was called

Comment: As a very simple example a constructor might be happy to take a Vector3d, Vector3f or an array of doubles (of size 3). In each case it (if nessissary) converts it to its prefered format of Vector3d before storing. If the constructor just guessed it would presumably store all 3 formats, all but 1 being null depending on which constructor you called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this would probably be possible in languages like Scala or Ceylon <sup>(see below)</sup>, in Java, you have to assign constructor arguments explictly to instance variables. Thus:

```
public class WineChiller {

    double wineTemp;
    double preferredTemp;
    double chillTemp;

    public WineChiller(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {
        this.wineTemp = wineTemp;
        this.preferredTemp = preferredTemp;
        this.chillTemp = chillTemp;

        getChillingTime();
    }
```

Constructor arguments are visible only in the scope of the constructor. The fact that the constructor calls your `getChillingTime()` is irrelevant. If you want them to be visible within the scope of a `WineChiller` instance, you'll have to create members in that class. All methods of that class can then access instance members.

Anyway, I strongly suggest you thoroughly read through a Java tutorial. Here's one:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial

### Constructors in other JVM languages

I think you're mainly struggling with the verbosity of Java, where you have to explicitly copy constructor arguments onto instance fields in order to implement [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation). Other languages have solved this more elegantly, where constructors can be implicitly defined along with the class itself. However, they would still translate to something equivalent of the above Java code. For instance:

#### Scala:

```scala
class Greeter(message: String) {
    def SayHi() = println(message)
}

val greeter = new Greeter("Hello world!")
greeter.SayHi()
```

<sub>Example from here: http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-four-classes-and-constructors/</sub>

#### Ceylon

```
class Point(Float x, Float y) { ... }
object origin extends Point(0.0, 0.0) {}
```

<sub>Example from here: http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.0/spec/html_single/</sub>

Comment: Well, the problem is that the instructions said that the method SHOULDN'T take arguments, and that the class WineChiller shouldn't contain anything but the constructor and the method getChillingTime.

Comment: Are you allowed to use further classes? If so, you can have a class that only has static members. These can be set in the constructor and called in `getChillingTime`.

Comment: @Benjamin I think the instructions are trying to force you to use fields (the no arguments in the method strongly suggests this). This doesnt suprise me as people unfamiliar to object orientated programmimg will often try to pass everythimg a function needs to do its work. Reading the "shouldnt contain amything else" and "no arguments to function" makes the problem impossible unless fields are exempted. It would also be a bizarre question to ask

Comment: Is this is a 101 java course or an advanced programmimg challenge (in which case bizzarre and unnatural acts might be the point)

Comment: It's 101. I suppose I misinterpreted - there was some kind of class diagram which listed the getChillingTime() method. I assumed the empty parenthesis meant that it shouldn't take any arguments. Maybe that was premature.

Comment: That would suprise me, because long term the empty getChillingTime () method is the right way to do it. The requirements of the problem are to point you in the right direction and to pass everything to the function would technically work but would be the wrong way to do it

Comment: @Benjamin If I was to do this completely without restrictions I'd make the preferedTemp and chillTemp fields as they're properties of the chiller, but I'd have the function take the wine temp as an argument because that changes from bottle to bottle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're expected to use fields. If this is about learning Java, then that's a very standard way to deal with encapsulation, and thus a good example for such a course.

Comment: In fact if you didn't use fields you might as well not bother creating an object at all; just use static methods for everything which take all the arguments they need. (This would be a bad idea and a complete subversion of java **do not do this**)

Comment: Well for this particular problem, I for one have a hard time seeing the benefits of an object oriented approach. Just a simple function containing userInput and a loop seems better to me, so as an excercise highlighting the importance of classes and objects, it seems misguided to me. Am I wrong?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: It's very simple to understand where you'll benefit from thinking ahead in object oriented design. Next you'll add `chill()`, `serve()`, `addMoreBottles()`, `removeBottles()` and dozens of other methods. Do you want to pass relevant "wine chiller properties" every time? What if you notice, heck I also need `dangerousTemp` and `suggestedTemp` ? Change 20 method signatures? Or do you want to let the wine chiller do its work? Anyway, this will be off-topic for Stack Overflow. Do read a tutorial on OO encapsulation. There are many out there.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist I don't nessissarily disagree. Often doing things in object orientated is harder for small programs and you wonder why you're doing it. But if you were given a large problem to start with you wouldn't know how to start

Comment: But as they get larger it begins to make more and more sense. I used to program large applications in VBA (shudder) and I remember the constant shifting sand. A function would be sensitive to exactly how other functions worked. A small change in one part of the program could cause huge errors elsewhere. Object orientated on the other hand is all about making promises. An object promises that once constructed it can perform any of the methods it defines. How it forfils those promises is entirely up to the object

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: That's how Java is. Often quite verbose. Verbosity is what's scaring you off right now, but you'll still get a lot of benefits if you're patient enough to write that code. See my updated answer for some other JVM languages, and how they deal with assigning constructor arguments to fields...

Comment: @LukasEder to go wildly off topic how do those languages deal with multiple constructors, or constructors that take objects that will be used to create the fields not used as fields directly

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist I actually like the Verbosity, i've used languages (like matlab) where the (for want of a better word) compiler does a lot of guessing. I once had a program writen by someone else that used a function with the same name as a native function and as long as the function was in the same folder the compiler guessed that that was the one you wanted. Of course they didn't include that function and I spent hours debugging. A simple requirement for import statements would have told me what was wrong

Comment: @RichardTingle: Hah, Ceylon doesn't allow overloading, and Scala is a very functional language, hence immutability is key. So both languages will encourage you to see constructor arguments as a way to construct members. But I think you can override that behaviour

Answer (score 2):

> The scope of variables passed to a method is the method itself

In other words, a variable passed to a method gets destroyed (garbage collected) once the method execution ends.

*Constructors are special kind of methods*, which are used to create that type's instances.

Since you **haven't** created a **copy** of the variables passed to the constructor in the type, they got lost, hence your error.

To make your code work, **declare** the **fields** in your class

```
public class WineChiller {

    private double wineTemp;
    private double preferredTemp;
    private double chillTemp;

    public WineChiller(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {
        this.wineTemp = wineTemp;
        this.preferredTemp = preferredTemp;
        this.chillTemp = chillTemp;
        getChillingTime();

    }

    public void getChillingTime() {

        while(wineTemp>preferredTemp)
        {
            elapsedTime += DELTA_MINUTES;
            double dT = (wineTemp - chillTemp) * DELTA_MINUTES  / TAO;
            wineTemp -= dT;
        }
        System.out.println(Math.round(elapsedTime));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't getChillingTime resolve wineTemp etc to variables?

Thats not how **local variables** work. `wineTemp` is only confined inside `WineChiller constructor`. you either have to pass it as argument to `getChillingTime()` method and use it or, make it an **instance variable** of your class.

```
 public WineChiller(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {
        getChillingTime(wineTemp);
    }
 public void getChillingTime(double wineTemp) {
```

**OR:**

```
public class WineChiller {
private double wineTemp;
    public WineChiller(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {
        this.wineTemp = wineTemp;
        getChillingTime();
    }
```

I recommend the 2nd approach which is standard way.

Answer (score 0):

the `wineTemp` you take in the constructor needs to be set somewhere so that it is accessible within the `getChillingTime` method.

**Proposed Fix**

```
    public class WineChiller {

        private double wineTemp;
        public WineChiller(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {
            this.wineTemp = wineTemp;
            ...
        }

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main function have it like this

```
WineChiller wineChiller = new WineChiller();
wineChiller.getChillingTime(wineTemp, preferredTemp, chillTemp);
```

IN your WineChiller class have the method to get those input

```
public void getChillingTime(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp)
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables passed as arguments to a method are local to that method only. If you wish to use them in another method, you must either store them as instance variable or pass them again as arguments.

```
public class WineChiller {

    double mWineTemp;
    double mPreferredTemp;
    double mChillTemp;

    public WineChiller(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {

        mWineTemp = wineTemp;
        mPreferredTemp = preferredTemp;
        mChillTemp = chillTemp;

        getChillingTime();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either, pass the arguments because the scope of parameters does not extend beyond the method itself

```
public WineChiller(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {
    getChillingTime(wineTemp, preferredTemp, chillTemp); // pass the arguments
}

public void getChillingTime(
            double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {
    // ...
}
```

Or, save them as *instance* member fields *(recommended)* which are automatically accessible from every *instance* method

```
public class WineChiller {

    // instance member fields
    private double wineTemp;
    private double preferredTemp;
    private double chillTemp;

    public WineChiller(double wineTemp, double preferredTemp, double chillTemp) {
        this.wineTemp = wineTemp;
        this.preferredTemp = preferredTemp;
        this.chillTemp = chillTemp;

        getChillingTime();
    }

    public void getChillingTime() {
        // ...
    }
}
```